# Barba.js (Pjax.js) and <head> replacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

I use [barba.js](http://barbajs.org/) to go through the pages without reloading and create a smooth animation.

This is an [example](http://agstudio.pro/project/barba/).

And a short code from the example:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    Barba.Pjax.init();
    Barba.Prefetch.init();

    var FadeTransition = Barba.BaseTransition.extend({
        start: function() {
            Promise
                .all([this.newContainerLoading, this.fadeOut()])
                .then(this.fadeIn.bind(this));
        },

        fadeOut: function() {
            return $(this.oldContainer).animate({
                opacity: 0
            }).promise();
        },

        fadeIn: function() {
            var _this = this;
            var $el = $(this.newContainer);

            $(this.oldContainer).hide();

            $el.css({
                visibility: 'visible',
                opacity: 0
            });

            $el.animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 400, function() {
                _this.done();
            });
        },

        newContainer: function() {
            var $newPageHead = $('<head />').html(
                $.parseHTML(
                    newPageRawHTML.match(/<head[^>]*>([\s\S.]*)<\/head>/i)[0], document, true
                )
            );
        },

        done: function() {
            var headTags = [
                "meta[name='keywords']",
                "meta[name='description']",
                "meta[property^='og']",
                "meta[name^='twitter']",
                "meta[itemprop]",
                "link[itemprop]",
                "link[rel='prev']",
                "link[rel='next']",
                "link[rel='canonical']"
            ].join(',');
            $('head').find(headTags).remove();
            $newPageHead.find(headTags).appendTo('head');
        }
    });

    Barba.Pjax.getTransition = function() {
        return FadeTransition;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/barba.js/0.0.10/barba.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="uMenuRoot">
  <li><a href="/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="/about.html"><span>About us</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="/contacts.html"><span>Contacts</span></a></li>
</ul>

<main id="barba-wrapper">
  <section class="barba-container middle">
    Page content   
  </section>
</main>
```

I wonder whether it is possible to reload `<head>`? Other words, extract the contents of the tag and replace already loaded `<head>` structure.

Also, It would be nice to replace not all the styles and scripts from `<head>`, but only some of the data. For example, OpenGraph markup.

Read more about the animation used in the example described [here](http://barbajs.org/transition.html).

Actually, we are talking about this part of the code:

```
newContainer: function() {
    var $newPageHead = $('<head />').html(
        $.parseHTML(
            newPageRawHTML.match(/<head[^>]*>([\s\S.]*)<\/head>/i)[0], document, true
        )
    );
},

done: function() {
    var headTags = [
        "meta[name='keywords']",
        "meta[name='description']",
        "meta[property^='og']",
        "meta[name^='twitter']",
        "meta[itemprop]",
        "link[itemprop]",
        "link[rel='prev']",
        "link[rel='next']",
        "link[rel='canonical']"
    ].join(',');
    $('head').find(headTags).remove();
    $newPageHead.find(headTags).appendTo('head');
}
```

In this part of the code I want to extract some items from the `<head>`, just from the page to be loaded. Then remove the same after the animation elements and replace them with previously received.

After the end of the animation, the selected elements disappear, but new ones are not added. What else has changed and I do not know. You can modify the sample code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/MRgZ6oE5s17QugpST5so?p=preview).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of Barba.js.

What you are asking has been already discussed on [github](https://github.com/luruke/barba.js/issues/82)

Is there a specific reason why you want to update the content of the head?
Bots/Crawler will fetch a page directly, so it will always have the correct head information.

If you really want to update those info, someone made a snippet code:
https://gist.github.com/grenouille220/58690c83d8c8d5c9308a35a240b34d69

Comment: Thanks for your work. This is a really awesome script. As for the discuss and snippet you showed in a reply. I tried to put that code and it isn't work for me. You can work with this [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/MRgZ6oE5s17QugpST5so?p=preview). I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: There you go: https://plnkr.co/edit/wfgMT7kbvX3mhoGDggli?p=preview

It was enough to switch to the latest version of Barba.js and copy-paste the snippet.

Comment: This is some kind of magic. I did the same a lot of times and it did not work. Thanks a lot! One last questions... is is possible to restart or reload some scripts from the `<head>` or `<body>`? And is it possible to set which element should be checked with the link parameter? As I understood, now it is all `<a>` tags. In general, is is possible to make the same control as [here](https://github.com/grenouille220/jquery-sail)?

Comment: You can use Barba.Views or the event system. Barba.js doesn't automatically inject/parse new script tag. (I suggest you to serve one minified/bundled js file anyway).

Barba.js automatically binds a tags, but you can manually go to a url using http://barbajs.org/docs/Barba.Pjax.html#.goTo

Comment: I know about `.no-barba`, but can I use snippet code for ignore links, or can I use barba only for navigation menu? Also, is it possible to use fade effect only for navigation and create [other animation](http://barbajs.org/demo/nextprev/index.html) for some articles.

Comment: I did almost everything I need and now I see, that your script is the best than others analog. I created [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/McOROzi0kOqIhLeVQkFT?p=preview) so you can see the result. I still didn't finish my work and I would be very grateful if you will help me with some issues. I can't restart some scripts, for example, I can't start google map in "contacts.html" and other script for mail form inside of the "barba-wrapper". Also, I can't stop animation for all links inside of some container. For example, inside of markup list with Barba.Pjax.preventCheck. Can you help me?